# Add a column of data to query

Tags: powershell, csv

I require an additional column added to this output called "Location" with each row of data containing the word "Varonis".

```
$fs | ForEach-Object {
    $machine = $_.ServerName
    $_.Volumes | Select-Object @{n='machine';e={$machine}}, Share, FileWalkMethod
} | Export-Csv D:\data\splunk\otl_varonis\otl_varonis_monitoring.csv -NoType
```

Current output:

```
"hmanas01n","E$","VaronisWindows"
```

Desired output:

```
"hmanas01n","E$","VaronisWindows", "Varonis"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially this is a question of how to add custom fields to an existing object (i.e. data)...

In the code example you give, the columns of output are defined by the following command:

```
Select-Object @{n='machine';e={$machine}}, Share, FileWalkMethod
```

This effectively filters the data to just the **Share** and **FileWalkMethod** properties, as well as adding a new column called **machine**. The **machine** column is defined with two key-value pairs: **n** (or name/label) is the column title and **e** (or expression) is a bit of code that sets the value for that column; in this case whatever the **$machine** variable is set to.

You need to replicate the same mechanism that adds the **machine** column by adding this to the end of the `Select-Object` statement, where the expression is just a static value:

```
@{n="Location";e={"Varonis"}}
```

Comment: Amazing man, I should have just followed my own logic! Thanks :)